# usb don't work for a time after boot with "usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110"

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 machine that's exhibiting a strange usb error during startup.

The keyboard doesn't work during boot. The system gets to the login screen and, for something like 30 seconds, the keyboard doesn't work, but the mouse does. Then the screen blinks and the keyboard begins to work.

I have checked the system log and found

```
device descriptor read/all, error -110
```

and then, in awhile

```
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 1-12: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-12: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=082d
usb 1-12: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb 1-12: Product: HD Pro Webcam C920
usb 1-12: SerialNumber: 153D0E9F
usb 1-13: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-13: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2005
usb 1-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-13: Product: DELL USB Keyboard
usb 1-13: Manufacturer: DELL
usb 1-13: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
```

If I try to shut down (using the mouse) before the keyboard becomes available, I'm getting a black screen with the following messages appearing, one-by-one:

```
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is this a BIOS, hardware, driver, or service error?

Comment: P.S. I just tried to switch the USB ports used by the keyboard and mouse. After this, the keyboard was working right away, but the mouse wasn't working until the screen blinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that worked for me.
First, some data which may be relevant to your case.
I have two machines with AsRock's Z97 boards.

- One is Z97 Fatality. I have checked and determined I don't suffer
  from this usb error causing boot-stall on that. If you have this
  board and are suffering from this issue, let me know and I will post
  my BIOS usb settings.
- Another is Z97 OC Formula (not Z97 Extreme). I had the problem on this one.

Here is how I solved the problem with the Z97 OC Formula:

1. Upgrade BIOS to latest version (P1.80 for me now)
2. (May be unrelated, but this happened between 1 & 3) Upgrade ubuntu to 16.04 or newer.
3. Reset CMOS (on board, using jumper, not "load defaults" through BIOS, that didn't help).

My USB settings in UEFI BIOS are as follows (unchanged since CMOS reset):

- USB Controller -> Enabled
- Intel USB 3.0 Mode -> Smart Auto
- Legacy USB Support -> Enabled
- Legacy USB 3.0 Support -> Enabled
- USB Compatibility Patch -> Disabled

I hope this helps someone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem with my machine for some time now. The problem exists on different distributions (I tried Ubuntu 15.10 and Arch kernel 4.4.7-1-lts). Here's an example where you can see the delay during startup:

```
[    8.455055] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s25: link becomes ready
[   11.223284] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   11.343240] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   21.483366] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   21.603279] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   26.596139] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   31.701949] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110                                                            
[   31.931143] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   36.939569] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   42.063696] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110                                                            
[   42.173434] usb usb1-port3: unable to enumerate USB device                                                           
[   42.293324] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   42.536287] usb-storage 1-8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   42.536650] scsi host11: usb-storage 1-8:1.0
[   42.653046] usb 1-13: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[   42.793388] hub 1-13:1.0: USB hub found
[   42.793420] hub 1-13:1.0: 3 ports detected
```

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110) says that the -110 error indicates power exceeded. I doubt this is the case for me - there simply aren't enough USB devices (just a keyboard and a mouse using the powered hub built into my monitor). We do have at least one thing in common - we both have Dell Keyboards. Are you also using a hub?

The last information I can add to this question is that this behavior seems to depend on your motherboard's USB BIOS settings. I have an Asrock Z87 Extreme6/ac and modifying the Intel USB3 behavior causes my system to break in various ways (from no USB devices working, to just USB3 devices, to this behavior). What motherboard do you have? Does the behavior change when modifying the settings? Be careful, I've had to clear my CMOS a couple times already because the keyboard would not longer function during BIOS startup!

Comment: I am not using a hub. I think I have this problem on two different machines, both have AsRock Z87 motherboards. One is Z87 Professional, one is Z87 Extreme. Also, both have Dell keyboards. I can try to mess around with the BIOS USB settings, but I don't know when I'll do it -- this isn't really critical for me right now. If you do strike upon settings that eliminate the problem for you, please let me know.

Comment: sorry to post incorrect info earlier, but I have the Z87 OC Formula board that had the issue, bot the Z87 Extreme. Check out founderio's answer  above to see if that helps you, or my own answer if that doesn't work: BIOS upgrade might just do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add my findings as a comment, I'll add it as an answer.

**My setup:** ASRock Z97 Extreme6 and Ubuntu 15.10

**What I found out so far:**
It seems related to Z97 & similar chipsets: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1437492

Solutions mentioned there are:

- Power off, pull the plug & wait a bit, then power on again -> works for one boot sequence
- Disable Asmedia controller / Asmedia USB controller or similar. These seem to be located in different spots depending on the board. I found 2 potential matches. `Advanced -> USB Configuration -> Third Party USB 3.0 Controller` and `Advanced -> Storage Configuration -> 'ASMedia SATA3 Mode'`

**So what I tried:**

- I began from a clean Config (Fresh after CMOS reset)
- The ASMedia setting in "Storage Configuration" I have tried in the past -> this disables some of the SATA ports, so I tried a different route first.
- Go to `Advanced -> USB Configuration -> Set 'Third Party Controller' to Disabled` **Result:** Boot sequence is still slow, but Ubuntu is back to normal speed. Well, my mouse did not work anymore (I had to switch to a different tty to reboot my computer...). Back to UEFI setup.
- Go to `Advanced -> USB Configuration -> Set 'Intel USB3.0 Mode' from 'Smart Auto' to 'Enabled'` **Result:** Scratch that, did not help. Only the front panel USBs work...
- Next I tried shutting down, cut the power for a few minutes, then boot again. **Result:** That did the trick. System boot time was just a few seconds total. And the USB ports on the back of my computer work again, too.
- Next: verify by rebooting again. **Result:** Yep, still working.
- Another update: Well, most of the ports work.. Some still don't work. But since I use a hub I can live with that for now. If you try it, maybe the power off & cut power is enough? Might be worth a try..

I'm not sure if all changes above are required - but it is working for me now, so I won't touch these again ;)

I hope this helps you & potentially other people stumbling across the same issue. I also recommend reading the launchpad bug linked above -> That bug report is worth it's weight in gold!

---

Below are some failed attempts messing with the Legacy Mode settings, that did not solve my problem. Summary: Legacy modes, Compatibility patches, etc. don't really improve the situation, they mostly just randomly disable your devices.. They might help others, so I leave them here for reference.

**Playing around with some settings I have found out the following:**

Note that I tried to set the USB 2.0 Legacy support to "UEFI Setup Only" so I could get into the setup by plugging the keyboard into the 2.0 ports on my front panel, just to be sure. **That did NOT work.** These ports are pretty much usesless & my keyboards only work when plugged into a port with legacy support enabled, OR into the hub on my monitor. Any, of yourse, only once Ubuntu started up. Neither UEFI nor Grub would recognize the keyboard. Another keyboard I could get to work on one of the 2.0 ports, so I could get around a CMOS reset.

**With "USB Compatibility Patch" enabled:**

When plugged directly into the USB 3.0 Ports on the Motherboard, they only work when I enabled USB 3.0 Legcy support in the UEFI setup. When I do that, boot sequence is ~20 seconds longer than the usual 1-3 seconds. Ubuntu then also takes longer to start up, with the `device descriptor read/all, error -110` errors, as displayed above. *The keyboard works, but the USB camera I have (Logitech QuickCam Communicate STX, pretty old..) is not recognized by the system.*

When the legacy mode is disabled but the two devices are plugged into the hub on my monitor (powered hub, I guess), boot sequence is blazingly fast if no device is plugged into the 2.0 ports BUT Ubuntu still takes longer & displays these messages. *Both keyboard and camera work.*

Legacy Mode enabled, pretty much yields the same result.

**With "USB Compatibility Patch" disabled:**
Same behaviour as above, but *the other keyboard on the 2.0 Port did not work either*... --> CMOS reset.

I'll experiment some more and update this answer as I gather results.

Comment: OK, first attempt with changing the USB Legacy mode settings did not work... See my edited answer for a solution that works for me.

Comment: I did not have the 'Third Party Controller' in my BIOS settings. That might be related to my board being Z87 OC Formula, not Z87 Extreme. But I did a BIOS upgrade & CMOS reset, and that seemed to do the trick (my answer below). I've checked USB & USB 3 ports, they all seem to be working.

Comment: Glad an update + reset works for you! For me the system seems to stall on that third party controller.. so.. yeah.. I'd rather live with a few less USB ports than with a system taking bloody ages to boot ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same error when I attached USB into one of port on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. In-case some one facing same issue so attaching here the solution which works for me:

A wireless keyboard (Receiver) was attached before plugging USB into the port. I  removed this wireless receiver and then plugged the USB again and it start working.